# JavaScript: 'Disallow leading _ in identifiers' as an option in JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have just started writing my own *JavaScript Framework* (just for the learning experience), and have prefixed some private members with a **_**, like such:

```
var _isFireBugEnabled = function () {
    return (window.console && window.console.firebug);
};
```

When I ran my code against Crockford's [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) (as always), with `Recommended Options` on, I was told about not using a _ as an identifier.

My question is, **Why does JSLint warn me as regards not using a _ as an identifier?**

Are there some side effects or implications I am missing here?

*PS. As far as I could scan just now, this is not documented in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that Douglas Crockford hates about 78% of Javascript*. Many people think he's a bit strict, and in fact many libraries do use leading underscores in production code.  I don't see much wrong with it.  There are no side effects.

Additionally, the '$', not the underscore, was the symbol set aside for "system" code by the [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

> **from ECMA 262, section 7.6:**
>
> This standard specifies one departure
>   from the grammar given in the Unicode
>   standard: The dollar sign ($) and the
>   underscore (_) are permitted anywhere
>   in an identifier. The dollar sign is
>   intended for use only in mechanically
>   generated code.

*Note: I'm being facetious. He really only hates about half, and he typically has good reason. I'd disagree with Crockford here, but he's usually very right.

Answer (score 8):

I've actually e-mailed Crockford on this. This was his response:

> I think _ should be reserved for
>   system code implementation, and not
>   used by applications.

I disagree with him somewhat, I tend to use _ to prefix truly private members in my own classes, because it makes it clear to me what is private. Google's Caja has some rules regarding the use of _, but nothing that should cause problems with what you're describing.

Comment: Caja only complains about 2 underscores, so {{{foo_}}} is fine, but {{{foo__}}} is verboten.  This is meant to, among other things, prevent accidental access to special interpreter properties like {{{__proto__}}}